# VS2013 Publish does not copy content folder in referenced class library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have the following folder structure:

```
Library <--[project ref]-- Web Project
--------                    -----------
DataFiles
EngineFiles
.cs files                   .cs files
```

All files contined both folders have `Build Action = Content` & `Copy To Output Directory = Copy Always`. When I build the solution the files are getting created inside the respective folders of the /bin directory (DataFiles & EngineFiles folders).

When I publish locally the files also get created inside the respective folders in the `/bin` directory of my Web Project.

However when I try to publish via TFS the files flattened inside the `/bin` folder of my `_PublishedWebsites`, the `DataFiles` & `EngineFiles` folders no longer exist. I am using a custom build template that we have been using without any problems up to this point.

This is what the Target section of our build template looks like:

```
  <Target Name="DropWebSiteUI">
    <Message Text="Drop Web Site UI files" />

    <CreateItem Include="$(BinariesRoot)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)\_PublishedWebsites\StackOverflow\**\*;">
      <Output ItemName="WebSiteUI" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>

    <CreateItem Include="$(BinariesRoot)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)\en-US\*;">
      <Output ItemName="ResourceFile_StackOverflowUI" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(WebSiteUI)" DestinationFiles="@(WebSiteUI-&gt;'$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\WebSiteUI\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)')" ContinueOnError="true" />

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ResourceFile_StackOverflowUI)" DestinationFiles="@(ResourceFile_StackOverlowUI-&gt;'$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\WebSiteUI\bin\en-US\%(FileName)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>
```

Any ideas as to why the folders are not getting copied over with the files included inside them?